# Join 2 elements of a list

Tags: python, list, zip

If I have 2 lists:

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

How can I get a 3rd list with the output

```
list3 = ['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d']
```

I have tried Zip and Join

but Zip still leaves the items separated and Join removes all the separators entirely

Thanks guys!

Comment: are you want to concatenate two list element wise ?

Comment: You're not using Python syntax.  Are all of these values meant to be strings?  Or just the ones that contains letters?  Post code that Python will accept.  Right now I see a list with numbers and a list that references variables, followed by a list that is invalid syntax.  I'm sure that's not what's intended.

Comment: "I have tried Zip and Join"--please show these attempts.

Comment: yes, list 2 is meant to be strings! thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine two items of two lists as string you need to iterate through both lists at the same time and concatenate the two items as strings.

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list3 = [str(x) + str(y) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
print(list3)
```

the output will be:

```
['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d']
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second list does not make any sense without defining variables `a`, `b`..., unless you mean strings?

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

list3 = [str(x) + y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```